# NEHotspotConfiguration is not working in ios 11

Tags: ios

I tried to connect the specific wifi with ssid and password using NEHotspotConfiguration, it has the internal server error.

Please help me if you have the answer for how to connect to a wifi AP on ios.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. To enable Network Extensions and Hotspot within App IDs.
2. Xcode -> TARGETS -> Capabilities open Network Extensions and Hotspot.
3. import  in the your code.

Here is my code, it may work for you:

```
-(IBAction) joinWiFi_ButtonPressed: (id) sender {

    if (@available (iOS 11.0, *)) {
        NEHotspotConfiguration * configuration = [[NEHotspotConfiguration alloc] initWithSSID: @ "Your SSID" passphrase:            @ "Password" isWEP: NO];
        configation.joinOnce = YES;
        [[NEHotspotConfigurationManager sharedManager] applyConfiguration: configuration completionHandler: ^ (NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog (@ "Is Connected!!");
        } else {
            NSLog (@ "Error is:% @", error);
        }}];
        } else {
            NSLog (@ "This Device Not iOS 11 +");
        }
    }
```

Can you post your error log? It could help me to better understand your question and refine my answer.

Comment: This code does not work for Open Network. For open network I changed NEHotspotConfiguration * configuration = [[NEHotspotConfiguration alloc] initWithSSID: @ "Your SSID" passphrase:            @ "Password" isWEP: NO]; to NEHotspotConfiguration * configuration = [[NEHotspotConfiguration alloc] initWithSSID: @ "Your SSID"]; Is this a bug in API I get error NEHotspotConfiguration valid:726  NEHotspotConfiguration invalid WPA/WPA2 passphrase length